# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^{58}\binom{2017+k}{58-k}\binom{2075-k}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{29}\binom{4091-2k}{58-2k}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Show that :

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{58}\binom{2017+k}{58-k}\binom{2075-k}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{29}\binom{4091-2k}{58-2k}$$

It seems interesting, but how to prove?

Comment: What contest is this from?

Comment: @mlc the LHS has $k$'s in the top of the binomial coefficients, Vandermonde's identity merely has constants.

Comment: @vrugtehagel You are right. (Sorry.) The suggestion in my comment is useless, so I am deleting it.

Comment: @JaideepKhare: Two answers belong to analytic combinatorics, one is purely combinatorial. Why do you think the tag *combinatorics* is not appropriate?

Answer (score 7):

We are interested in verifying that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} {m+k\choose 2n-k} {m+2n-k\choose k}
= \sum_{k=0}^n {2m+2n-1-2k\choose 2n-2k}.$$

Starting with the RHS we introduce

$${2m+2n-1-2k\choose 2n-2k} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{2n-2k+1}} (1+z)^{2m+2n-1-2k} \; dz.$$

Note that this vanishes when $k\gt n$ so we may extend $k$ to infinity
and obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} (1+z)^{2m+2n-1}
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{z^{2k}}{(1+z)^{2k}} 
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} (1+z)^{2m+2n-1}
\frac{1}{1-z^2/(1+z)^2}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{2n+1}} (1+z)^{2m+2n+1}
\frac{1}{1+2z}
\; dz.$$

For the LHS we introduce

$${m+2n-k\choose k} = {m+2n-k\choose m+2n-2k} \\ =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m+2n-2k+1}} (1+z)^{m+2n-k} \; dz$$

as well as

$${m+k\choose 2n-k} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{2n-k+1}} (1+w)^{m+k}
\; dw.$$

This last one vanishes when $k\gt  2n$ so it controls the range and we
may extend $k$ to infinity and obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{2n+1}} (1+w)^{m}
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m+2n+1}} (1+z)^{m+2n} 
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{z^{2k} w^k (1+w)^k}{(1+z)^k}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{2n+1}} (1+w)^{m}
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m+2n+1}} (1+z)^{m+2n} 
\frac{1}{1-z^2 w(1+w)/(1+z)}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{2n+1}} (1+w)^{m}
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m+2n+1}} (1+z)^{m+2n+1} 
\frac{1}{(z(1+w)+1)(wz-1)}
\; dz \; dw.$$

We will  evaluate the inner integral  using the fact  that residues at
the poles  sum to zero. Fortunately  the residue at  infinity is zero,
which can be seen by inspection, or more formally through

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} 
\frac{1}{z^{m+2n+1}} (1+z)^{m+2n+1} 
\frac{1}{(z(1+w)+1)(wz-1)}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2}
z^{m+2n+1} (1+1/z)^{m+2n+1} 
\frac{1}{((1+w)/z+1)(w/z-1)}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{z=0}
(z+1)^{m+2n+1} 
\frac{1}{((1+w)+z)(w-z)} = 0.$$

To facilitate extraction of residues we write the integral as

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{2n+2}} (1+w)^{m-1}
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{m+2n+1}} (1+z)^{m+2n+1} 
\frac{1}{(z+1/(1+w))(z-1/w)}
\; dz \; dw.$$

Flipping the sign we get from the residue at $-1/(1+w)$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{2n+2}} (1+w)^{m-1} \\ \times
(-1)^{m+2n+1} (1+w)^{m+2n+1} \frac{w^{m+2n+1}}{(1+w)^{m+2n+1}}
\frac{1}{-1/(w+1)-1/w} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{2n+2}} (1+w)^{m-1} \\ \times
(-1)^{m+2n+1} w^{m+2n+1}
\frac{w(w+1)}{-w-(1+w)} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
 (1+w)^{m}
(-1)^{m+2n} w^{m}
\frac{1}{1+2w} \; dw = 0.$$

Once more flipping the sign we get from the residue at $z=1/w$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{2n+2}} (1+w)^{m-1} \\ \times
w^{m+2n+1} \frac{(1+w)^{m+2n+1}}{w^{m+2n+1}} 
\frac{1}{1/w+1/(1+w)} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{2n+2}} (1+w)^{2m+2n}
\frac{w(1+w)}{1+w+w} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{2n+1}} (1+w)^{2m+2n+1}
\frac{1}{1+2w} \; dw.$$

We have  obtained exactly the  same integral as  for the RHS  and this
concludes  the argument.  If a  closed  form for  easy computation  is
desired then it would be

$$\sum_{q=0}^{2n} {2m+2n+1\choose q} (-1)^{2n-q} 2^{2n-q}$$

or at last

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
2^{2n} \sum_{q=0}^{2n} {2m+2n+1\choose q}
\frac{(-1)^q}{2^q}.}$$

**Remark.** Considering  the origins of  this problem as  listed in
the comments   we  suspect  that an  elementary proof or at  any  rate
one using formal power series is  certain to appear in addition to the 
Egorychev method which is what I have above.

Comment: I think can other methods to prove it

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Very nice! (+1)

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** This is a merely a variation of @MarkoRiedel's nice answer which was a pleasure to analyse. It's based upon the same technique, but uses another notation which might also be convenient. In order to ease comparison I use the same variables.

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> The following generalisation of OPs identity is valid for $m,n\geq 0$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{2n} {m+k\choose 2n-k} {m+2n-k\choose k}
> = \sum_{k=0}^n {2m+2n-1-2k\choose 2n-2k}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> We start with the RHS of (1) and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n {2m+2n-1-2k\choose 2n-2k}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty[z^{2n-2k}](1+z)^{2m+2n-1-2k}\tag{2}\\
> &=[z^{2n}](1+z)^{2m+2n-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left( \frac{z}{1+z}\right)^{2k}\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^{2n}](1+z)^{2m+2n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{1- \frac{z^2}{(1+z)^2}}\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^{2n}]\frac{(1+z)^{2m+2n+1}}{1-2z}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator once and change the upper limit of the sum to $\infty$ without changing anything since we adding zeros only.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)]=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (4) we use the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* formula.
- In (5) we do some simplifications and represent the RHS as coefficient of $z^{2n}$ of a *[rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function)*.

The goal is to transform the LHS of (1) also to (5) and show this way equality.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{2n}&\binom{m+k}{2n-k}\binom{m+2n-k}{k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{m+k}{2n-k}\binom{m+2n-k}{m+2n-2k}\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty[w^{2n-k}](1+w)^{m+k}[z^{m+2n-2k}](1+z)^{m+2n-k}\\
> &=[w^{2n}](1+w)^{m}[z^{m+2n}](1+z)^{m+2n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{z^2w(1+w)}{1+z}\right)^k\\
> &=[w^{2n}](1+w)^{m}[z^{m+2n}](1+z)^{m+2n}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2w(1+w)}{1+z}}\tag{7}\\
> &=-[w^{2n}](1+w)^{m}[z^{m+2n}](1+z)^{m+2n}\cdot\frac{\frac{1+z}{w(1+w)}}{\left(z-\frac{1}{w}\right)\left(z+\frac{1}{1+w}\right)}\tag{8}\\
> &=-[w^{2n+1}](1+w)^{m-1}[z^{-1}]\underbrace{\frac{z^{-m-2n-1}(1+z)^{m+2n+1}}{\left(z-\frac{1}{w}\right)\left(z+\frac{1}{1+w}\right)}}_{f(z)}\tag{9}\\
> &=-[w^{2n+1}](1+w)^{m-1}
> \left(-\operatorname{res}_{z=\infty}f(z)-\operatorname{res}_{z=\frac{1}{w}}f(z)-\operatorname{res}_{z=-\frac{1}{1+w}}f(z)\right)\tag{10}\\
> &=[w^{2n+1}](1+w)^{m-1}\\
> &\qquad\cdot\left([z^{-1}]\left(-\frac{1}{z^2}\cdot
> \frac{\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{-m-2n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^{m+2n+1}}
> {\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{w}\right)\left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{1+w}\right)}\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{w}\right)^{-m-2n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{w}\right)^{m+2n+1}}{\frac{1}{w}+\frac{1}{1+w}}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\left.+\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{1+w}\right)^{-m-2n-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+w}\right)^{m+2n+1}}{-\frac{1}{1+w}-\frac{1}{w}}\right)\tag{11}\\
> &=[w^{2n+1}](1+w)^{m-1}\left([z^{-1}]\left(-\frac{(1+z)^{m+2n+1}}{\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{w}\right)\left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{1+w}\right)}\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad+\frac{w(1+w)^{m+2n+2}}{1+2w}+(-1)^m\frac{w^{m+2n+2}(1+w)}{1+2w}\Bigg)\tag{12}\\
> &=[w^{2n}]\frac{(1+w)^{2m+2n+1}}{1+2w}\tag{13}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (6) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (7) and the lines before we do the same steps as we already did for the RHS.
- In (8) we observe that we have a rational function in $z$ with simple poles at $z=\frac{1}{w}$ and $z=-\frac{1}{1+w}$.
- In (9) we write the $z$-part of the expression as *[residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis))* of a function $f(z)$.
- In (10) we use the fact that computing the residue of $f$ at zero is minus the sum of the residuals of $f$ at the poles and infinity.
- In (11) we use for the *[residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Residue_at_infinity)* the formula
  \begin{align*}
  \operatorname{res}_{z=\infty}f(z)=\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\left(-\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)
  =[z^{-1}]\left(-\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)
  \end{align*}
  and for a *[simple pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles)* $ a\in\mathbb{C}$ we use
  \begin{align*}
  \operatorname{res}_{z=a}f(z)=\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (12) we see the three residuals after some simplifications and observe that only the residue at $z=\frac{1}{w}$ has a contribution not equal to zero.
- In (13) we finally have the same situation as in (5).

> **Note:** Don Knuth et al. tell us in section 5.5 of *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*: 
>   Binomial coefficients are like *chameleons*, changing their appearance easily.
>
> In agreement with this statement we rewrite identity (1) putting  emphasis on symmetry. The following is valid for $m,n\geq 0$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=-n}^n\binom{n+m+k}{n-k}\binom{n+m-k}{n+k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{-2m}{2n-2k}
> \end{align*}

Here we shift the index $k$ of the LHS of (1) by $n$ to start from $-n$. On the other side we use the binomial identity 
$
\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q
$.

Maybe someone could derive some other insight from this more symmetrical representation.

Comment: This is very nice work. I will do some more checking but it looks good. It is the first time you used the sum-of-residues-is-zero rule for rational functions, which is immensely powerful and yields a variety of interesting results. (+1).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks a lot Marko! Although I've learned it many years ago in complex analysis, I wasn't aware it could be that useful in solving binomial identities. Usually, I'm trying to solve them with some less powerful techniques, but it's a good feeling to have it in the repertoire. :-) Even if some binomial identities look like a wall of stones, this technique is like a soft breath, a light dance around the poles and all the walls collapse. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Imagine having $N+2m$ boxes in a row. We need to pick $N$ boxes to be *special*, but in such a way that we can choose an $s$ such that of the first $m+s$ boxes, there are exactly $N-s$ boxes special.

This is quite a strange property, so let's see where this can go wrong. What are ways to pick the boxes that do not satisfy the property? Let's just loop through $s$ to see what's going on. We start with $s=0$. The property now says that of the first $m$ boxes, $N$ need to be special. Let's assume this is not true; there are less than $N$ boxes special in the first $m$ boxes. Then we increase $s$ by one; now there need to be $N-1$ boxes special in the first $m+1$ boxes. If there are *more* boxes special, then this means there were $N-1$ boxes of the first $m$ special, and the $m+1$'th box was special. We know now that there are no other $s$'s for which this can go right, since of the first $m+s$ boxes, there will be $N$ special (not $N-s$, as we should have).

> if there are less than $N-s$ boxes special of the first $m+s$ boxes, but more than $N-s-1$ out of the first $m+s+1$, then of the first $m+s$ boxes there are exactly $N-s-1$ special ones, furthermore, the $m+s+1$'st box is special. This results in an invalid way to pick our boxes (note that this only makes sense when $0\leq s<N$).

So the number of ways we can pick boxes in an *invalid* way, is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}{m+k\choose N-k-1}{m+N-k-1\choose k}$$

since we pick the $m+k+1$'th box to be special, and then pick $N-k-1$ boxes before that, and $k$ boxes after that.

The number of ways to pick boxes in a valid way, is of course

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N}{m+k\choose N-k}{m+N-k\choose k}$$

Notice that the number of ways to pick boxes in an invalid way, is the same as picking $N-1$ boxes out of $2m+N-1$, but in such a way that we can choose an $s$ such that of the first $m+s$, there are exactly $N-1-s$ boxes special. Can you hear induction screaming to be used?

Let's write $S_{2m}(N)$ to mean the number of ways that we can choose $N$ boxes out of $2m+N$, but in such a way that we can choose an $s$ (between $0$ and $N$) such that of the first $m+s$, there are exactly $N-s$ boxes special. Then, as noted above, we know that the number of ways to *not* do this, is $S_{2m}(N-1)$. Thus,

$${2m+N\choose N}=S_{2m}(N)+S_{2m}(N-1)$$

We will now use induction to prove

> $$S_{2m}(N)=\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^{N-k}{2m+k\choose k}$$

We know that $S_{2m}(0)=1$, and so $S_{2m}(0)={m+0\choose 0}$ is indeed true. Now, assume the expression is true for $N$. Then:
\begin{align}
S_{2m}(N+1)&={2m+N+1\choose N+1}-S_{2m}(N)\\
&={2m+N+1\choose N+1}-\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^{N-k}{2m+k\choose k}\\
&=(-1)^{N+1-(N+1)}{2m+N+1\choose N+1}+\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^{N+1-k}{2m+k\choose k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{N+1}(-1)^{N+1-k}{2m+k\choose k}\\
\end{align}
and so we can conclude that the expression must be true for all $N\geq0$.

---

So far, we've proven that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N}{m+k\choose N-k}{m+N-k\choose k}=\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^{N-k}{2m+k\choose k}$$

Let's now set $2n$, so that we get

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{m+k\choose 2n-k}{m+2n-k\choose k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^k{2m+k\choose k}$$

And now we just mess around a little bit with the right-hand side (I use ${a\choose-1}=0$ here):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^k{2m+k\choose k}&=\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2m+2k\choose 2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}{2m+2k-1\choose 2k-1}&=\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left({2m+2k-1\choose 2k}+{2m+2k-1\choose 2k-1}\right)-\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2m+2k-1\choose 2k-1}&=\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2m+2k-1\choose 2k}&=\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2m+2(n-k)-1\choose 2(n-k)}&=\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2m+2n-2k-1\choose 2n-2k}
\end{align}

so finally, we can conclude

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{m+k\choose 2n-k}{m+2n-k\choose k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2m+2n-2k-1\choose 2n-2k}$$

(and the requested result is obtained by setting $n=29$ and $m=2017$).

Comment: I was working on exactly the same line. You were faster. Congratulations!!! A very well deserved +1! Some passages would benefit from the notation $\left(\binom{a}{b}\right) = \binom{a+b-1}{b} = \left(\binom{b+1}{a-1}\right)=\frac{a}{b}\cdot\left(\binom{b}{a}\right)$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, I have never seen that notation before; does that have a name, so I can research it a little bit?

Comment: It’s called [_multiset number_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets) and it is used in [_Stars-and-bars_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) enumerations.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely play around with that for a bit. I won't change my answer (perhaps later) as for now, I'm not quite comfortable yet with that new notation.