# Limit of a sequence (binomial series and generating function for Catalan)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, binomial-theorem

Let $0 < |x|<1$ and let 
$$a_n = \sum_{i = n+1}^\infty \frac{i-n}{i+1}\binom{2i}{i}x^i.$$ 
And I am trying to show that 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0. $$

I am trying to use the following equality:
\begin{align}
f_n(x) &= \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{(i-n)}{i+1}\binom{2i}{i}x^i \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}} - (n+1)\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}
\end{align}
which can be obtained by using [LINK](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240927/random-walk-with-3-cases/2241002#2241002).
But not sure how to involve this...

Any comments or suggestions will be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|x|< 1/4$ the sequence converges to $0$.

There is a simple upper bound given by:
$$|a_n| \le \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{i-n}{i+1} \binom{2i}{i} |x|^i \le \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \binom{2i}{i} |x|^i$$
since $\frac{i-n}{i+1} <1$.

Now, it is natural to consider the series
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \binom{2i}{i} |x|^i$$
which is convergent by the ratio test (the radius of convergence is $1/4$). Thus, the remainders get infinitesimal
$$\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \binom{2i}{i} |x|^i \to 0$$
Giving you $|a_n| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.